# Connection with Grails to DB2 database

Tags: grails, connection, db2

I'm trying to connect my grails application to a DB2 database that is running locally. When I want to launch my app, I get multiples errors? I'm only getting started on grails and even more on DB2 database management. Can someone help me out ?

Here's the error trails

```
    Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DTH3_E:currentSchema=DFP_V115'
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DTH3_E:currentSchema=DFP_V115'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DTH3_E:currentSchema=DFP_V115'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DTH3_E:currentSchema=DFP_V115'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DTH3_E:currentSchema=DFP_V115'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DTH3_E:currentSchema=DFP_V115'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.h2.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DTH3_E:currentSchema=DFP_V115'
->> 1452 | createConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1371 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLException: No suitable driver
->> 264 | getDriver in java.sql.DriverManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1437 | createConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1371 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

and in my datasource.groovy file, here's what I changed :

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            url = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DTH3_E:currentSchema=DFP_V115"
        }
    }
....
```

With some research, I understood that it was my hibernate config. Can anyone (in)validate ? And where do I go next...pretty lost to say the least

If wondering, the database is up and running and I'm able to connect to it using DbVisualizer.

Thanks in advance for the help ! If more details are needed, ask :) I'll try to clarify as much as possible the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your Exception, Grails is trying to use the H2 JDBC driver to connect to your DB2 database.  Try specifying the DB2 Hibernate dialect in your `dataSource` declaration to see if it will use the correct driver:

```
dataSource {
    dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"
}
```

Also make sure you have the necessary DB2 jar in you Grails project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip...Ran into another problem and I think it's because the user doesn't have all the rights on the database. In DB2, you know how to grant all rights to a user ? I'm using the DB on local, so doesn't matter if I screw up something (user name : dthdbusr)

Comment: Sorry.  I've never used DB2, so I can't help with user permissions.